# Xcode 6 architecture error simulator works , real device does not

Tags: xcode, swift

I am working on an app for a final xcode project in school. I am running Xcode 6.3. My problem is with the Architecture section. It compiles 100% correctly on all device simulators. I am a registered apple developer, so I want to test it on my Apple iPad MC705LL/A (16GB, Wi-Fi, Black) 3rd Generation. When I test it on my ipad or my iphone 5c, I get the following error:

Check dependencies

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 arm64, VALID_ARCHS=).

Any help would be appreciated. I just dont understand why it wont work on a real device.

Comment: please, post the screenshot of Project -> Build settings -> Architectures section. Let's see whether it is okay.

Comment: It doesn't work on a real device because of the way that your project is set up. Simulator compiles for x86 or x86-64, while real device needs armv7 or arm64. Probably something wrong in VALID_ARCHS section.